# Deleting img tag from string

Tags: php, image, string-parsing

I've got a string, `$content`, that contains:

```
<p>Some random text <img class="alignnone" src="logo.png" alt="" width="1920" height="648"></p>
```

Now I want to delete the image tag:

```
<img class="alignnone" src="logo.png" alt="" width="1920" height="648">
```

I tried `strip_tags` but that isn't working anymore.

```
$content = strip_tags($content, '<img></img>');
```

Comment: the second argument of `strip_tags` is `allowable tags`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working example.

```
<?php

$content = "<p>Some random text <img class=\"alignnone\" src=\"logo.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"1920\" height=\"648\"></p>";

echo strip_tags($content,"<p>");

?>
```

Comment: Excellent use of built-in PHP function. No sense in reinventing the wheel so to speak.

Comment: @Downvoter - Could you please tell me why you downvoted the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If `<p></p>` is the only other tag you'll have you can use `strip_tags` like this:

```
$content = strip_tags($content, '<p></p>');
```

If there may be other tags you want to keep, just add them to the second argument of `strip_tags`

You can also use a combination of string functions to achieve this:

```
$count = substr_count($c, '<img ');
while($count >= 1){

    $i = strpos($c, '<img ');
    $j = strpos($c, '>',$i)+1;
    $c = substr($c, 0,$i) . substr($c,$j);

    $count--;
}
echo $c;
```

This also takes care of multiple `<img>` tags

Answer (score -1):

You could search for the img-Tags with the strpos()-function:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strpos.asp

Once you know the start- and ending-position inside the string you can access the parts you need with the substr()-function:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php

In your example:

```
$left = strpos($content,'<img');
//$left should now be "20"
//to find the closing >-tag you need the string starting from <img... so you assign that to $rest:
$rest = substr($content,(strlen($content)-$left+1)*(-1));
$right = strpos($rest,">")+$left;
//now you know where the img ends so you can get the string surrounding it with:
$surr = substr($content,0,$left).substr($content,(strlen($content)-$right)*(-1));
```

Edit: Tested, will work for deleting the first img-Tag

Comment: It will find and delete the first image

Comment: You should test it, it wont work as is. Look at my answer for a much easier approach.